# When will the complement of a hypercube be bipartite?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know that every hyper cube is bipartite, but I am lost when it comes to their complements... I'm try to go off the theorem that "A graph is bipartite if and only if it does not contain any odd cycles", but I am having a hard time visualizing exactly when a hyper cube has odd cycles. Any hints to tackle this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The vertices $(\color{red}{0,0,0},0,\cdots)$, $(\color{red}{1,1,0},0,\cdots)$,$(\color{red}{1,0,1},0,\cdots)$ will form a $3-$cycle.

Comment: A takeaway from this: Yes, the hypercube can be thought of geometrically as an $n$ dimensional object.  But when you're trying to understand and work with the hypercube *graph*, it's often easier to work directly with the definition in terms of $0$s and $1$s instead of trying to visualize a high-dimensional object geometrically.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, for which values of $n$ the graph $\overline Q_n$, the complement of the cube $Q_n,$
is $2$-colorable (i.e., bipartite).

You know that $Q_n$ is $2$-colorable and has $2^n$ vertices. In a proper $2$-coloring of $Q_n,$ there are $2^{n-1}$ vertices of each color. The $2^{n-1}$ vertices of one color form a clique in the complementary graph $\overline Q_n,$ so $\chi(\overline Q_n)\ge2^{n-1}.$ Therefore $\overline Q_n$ is not $2$-colorable when $n\ge3.$

In fact, it is quite easy to see that $\chi(\overline Q_n)=2^{n-1}$ for all $n\ge1,$ whence $\overline Q_n$ is $2$-colorable if and only if $n\le2.$